# Random Word from Website

Tags: python-2.7

I have a simple program (not related to school) that requires a lot of random words in the local database. Earlier today, I found this website http://www.setgetgo.com/randomword/get.php that will always generate a random word every time the page is reloaded. I have an idea to create a variable that will consistently grab the value from this website, and append it to my list (acts as a local database).

Any idea how to do that? I thought there is a "wget" library in python too. However, my python keeps returning an error.

My idea:

> a_variable = *wget the website text*

Comment: This is a terrible idea. Google 'wordlist' and download one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the block of code you need

```
import requests
res = requests.get("http://www.setgetgo.com/randomword/get.php")
print res.content
```

I would adivce you to dive into [Request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). If you want to learn more about it.
Goodluck

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @ThomasWest If it helped, could you please accept it has the answer. :)